# Proper use of aggregation (OOP) with an electronic circuit class as an example

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm having trouble with how to organize my code with proper OOP practices.

Let's say I have an electronic circuit made of components such as resistors and a battery.

I would for sure want a class to analyze properties of the circuit as a whole. But there are also properties of the components that the circuit as a whole doesn't 'care' about.

My question is how should my battery and resistor classes interact with the circuit class?

I've written some sample code below that will hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to do. Please correct / comment on the implementation!

```
public class Circuit{
     public double current;
     public double supplyVoltage;
     public int numResistors;

     public double batteryVoltage(){
          //Create battery object here? Or in its own method?
          return supplyVoltage;
          }

     public double voltageDropAcrossResistor(){
          //Use V=I*R

          //Would I create Resistor objects here? Or create a method?
          //Does the circuit object 'remember' resistor objects
          //that were created elsewhere?
     }


}

public class Resistor{
     public int resistance;

     public void setResistance(int resistance){
         this.resistance = resistance;
     }
     public int getResistance(){
         return resistance;
     }
     public String getColorCode(){
         String color = someFormula; 
         return color; 
     }

}

public class Battery{
    public int voltage;
    public String batteryType;

    public void setVoltage(int voltage){
        this.voltage = voltage; 
    }
    public int getVoltage(){
       return voltage;
    }
    public void setBatteryType(String type){
        this.batteryType = type;
    }
    public String getBatteryType(){
        return batteryType; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that `Circuit` doesn't aggregate a `Battery` and a bunch of `Circuit`s in your design.

I'd expect object references such as:

```
public class Circuit {
    private Battery battery;
    private List<Resistor> resistors;

    public Circuit(Battery battery, List<Resistor> resistors) {
        //...
    }
```

Given that aggregation, the `Circuit` could ask the battery for it's voltage and could also get the resistance of it's resistors in order to compute the voltage drop.

> My question is how should my battery and resistor classes interact
>   with the circuit class?

Bidirectional relationships are not often required nor desired, especially with aggregation since the children have a lifecycle independent of their parent.  In this case the battery or resistors probably doesn't have to be aware of the circuit at all. They must however provide an adequate public interface to service the circuit (or any other components using them).

By the way, if you do not require batteries or resistors to have their own lifecycle you should rather speak of composition instead of aggregation.

Comment: In my case I do want the resistor to be aware of the circuit. Let's say the circuit only accepts surface mount components - I need my resistor class to know that. So essentially I don't know my resistor until I know some things about the circuit. Is that bidirectional?

Comment: Not necessarily, so you need to know some details about the circuit to choose the right type or amount of resistors? Is that right? I know nothing about circuits btw. However in this case you could have a circuit factory responsible of building the circuit properly. The circuit itself could even validate it was constructed with valid resistors. Perhaps you are missing a circuit component abstraction here.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation is `has-a` relationship, so in your case of a `Circut` it has `Battery` and `Resistor` your `Circut` class might then look a little like this:

```
private Battery battery;
private Resistor resistor;

public void addBattery(Battery battery) {
    this.battery = battery;
}

public void addResistor(Resistor resistor) {
    this.resistor = resistor;
}
```

So your return methods would then look like this:

```
public double batteryVoltage() {
    if (battery!=null) { // your formula and return value}
    return 0;
}
```

However, if `Battery` and `Resistor` are both expected values then you're using composition so you'd have to create a `Circut` constructor that accepts both components as parameters rather than setting them.

Comment: How would this work if I had 5 resistors of differing values, though?

Comment: Just change the method to accept a parameter of `List<Resistor>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use an aggregation.

You should add a battery-field and a field holding a container (for ex. a List) containing the resistors in your Circuit class.
You can initialize them outside of the Curcuit class and pass them into the Circuit-Constructor by using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your class is a good example of aggregation since **An A object is made up of B**
or in your example your circuit is made up of batteries and resistors...

What you are missing is some fields in Circuit class of the type Battery and REsistors

[image]